# Add custom QWidget to another QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to add an objects (that inherits from `QWidget`) as a child to another `QWidget` as shown below, it works perfectly with another normal `QWidget` instance but not with my custom class, any idea why ?

**fenetre.h**

```
#ifndef FENETRE_H
#define FENETRE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class Fenetre : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Fenetre();
};

#endif // FENETRE_H
```

**fenetre.cpp**

```
#include "fenetre.h"

Fenetre::Fenetre() : QWidget()
{

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include "fenetre.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    QWidget window;
    window.setFixedSize(800,600);

    //This appears
    QWidget rec1;
    rec1.setParent(&window);
    rec1.setFixedSize(100,100);
    rec1.move(400,200);
    rec1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red");

    //This one not
    Fenetre rec2;
    rec2.setParent(&window);
    rec2.setFixedSize(100,100);
    rec2.move(200,200);
    rec2.setStyleSheet("background-color: green");

    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

PS: I did research on the platform, but the majority of the answers speak of the use of a layout. Thank you !

Comment: I tried to reproduce your MCVE with Windows10/VS2017/Qt5.13 as well as with cygwin/g++/Qt5.9. In both cases, I got red and green box. The only change I did: exclude `Q_OBJECT` from `class fenetre` (as I wasn't able to involve moc properly and haven't any experience with it). In this MCVE, `Q_OBJECT` is probably rather useless - not sure if it plays a role for your issue...

Comment: @Scheff thank you, the problem was the `setStyleSheet()` function,  
I had to implement the `paintEvent` function in my custom class to make it work.

Comment: What do you do in `fenetre::paintEvent()`? It should be inherited from `QWidget()`, shouldn't it? In my case, it worked without `paintEvent()`. I just copy/pasted your code and the only thing I did was to change `Q_OBJECT` into `//Q_OBJECT`. Could it be that introducing a new meta-type for `class fenetre` has such consequences?

Comment: According to this [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget), we need to provide a `paintEvent` to the custom widget

Comment: This wiki mentioned Symbian OS. I didn't need a `paintEvent()`. (I swear.) ;-) On what OS, you did run your test?

Comment: On the Windows OS, the `paintEvent()` comme with the use of the `setStyleSheet` function i think. (i'm still new to Qt)

Comment: On any OS, a `QWidget` has a [QWidget::paintEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) and every derived class inherits it. Though, I was a bit surprised when I saw its impl. in woboq: [QWidget::paintEvent()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZN7QWidget10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent). :-) It's just empty. So, if a `QWidget` is able to draw a red background that doesn't happen in `paintEvent()` but in other code (where the `paintEvent()` is called).

Answer (score 0):

you miss the parent:

```
//header .h
class Fenetre : public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Fenetre(QWidget *parent = 0);
};

//source .cpp
Fenetre::Fenetre(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}
```